# How can I get my API upload multiple files with a certain extension to work?

Tags: python, json, api, recursion, python-requests

I'm new to programming and am trying to resolve this script to upload data, but I can't get it to work and I don't know why. I am modifying a script I already had to work with a single file, but I need to upload over 3,000 files with a specific extension (.json) in the specific file directory. I am getting an error on the 'f.read(open(files, 'r')) line. The error I get is there is no read extension for f. Not sure what I am doing incorrectly. I've researched it and still can't fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import requests
import time
import csv
import json
import glob
from glob import glob

# function to post data
def postData(xactData):
    url = 'api address'
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': str(len(xactData)),
        'Request-Timeout': '2000000000'
    }
    return requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=xactData)

# read data
f = r'path to file'

# iterate over all files with extension path .json
for files in glob(f + '/*.json'):
    my_data = f.read(open(files, 'r'))
    print(files) # print the files that have been uploaded to the api
    print(my_data) # print the data uploaded to the api

# post the data to the database
result = postData(my_data)
print(result)
```

Comment: `f` is of `str` type and not `FileIO`. You want to reference to the result from the call to `open` function and then call `read` on that. Also remember to close the file. Does the said API endpoint support batched file uploads?

Comment: Try `with open(f) as file_handle: my_data = f.read()`. If you have 3k uploads, try opening a requests session and/or adding threads.